# POSTGRES:could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

Tags: postgresql

I checked similar problems here,but didn't find any usefull help.
Using Windows 8.1 Pro.
I'm very new to use Postgres,I just downloaded version 12.4 today.
In setup wizard I leaved cluster set on  as default.
Then set my superuser password(pass123) when asked during the Wizard.
After launch postgres in pgAdmin4 I retype the password(pass123) and all is OK,but when I try to open Postgres12 Server, then ask me another time the password,so I retype pass123,but I receive this error:

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

1. The service of Postgres is already running in services.msc
2. No firewall blocking my port 5433
3. Here's my file pg_hba:
   TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

4)in pgAdmin4 Connection tab:

Hostname/address:localhost
port:5433
Manteinance Database:postgres
Username:postgres

Can someone please help me to handle this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you verify in `postgresql.conf` that the server is really running on port 5433?

Comment: Yes, correct! In that configuration file, the port was set to port 5432 instead of port 5433. Now is connecting fine. Thank you so much!